# Where's python-argparse package in RHEL?

Tags: python, rhel

I'm using python's argparse package in **CentOS6**. I installed it by the following command.

```
# yum install python-argparse
```

However, I could not find the package in **RHEL5 and 6**. Where is it? How can I get argparse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to install python packages via **easy_install** or **pip**:

```
# easy_install argparse

# pip install argparse
```

you can install **easy_install** or **pip** via your package manager.

Comment: Thanks. I could install via pip! `easy_install pip && pip install argparse`

Comment: In RHEL5, I had to install "python-setuptools" package first.

Comment: // , You can also put argparse.py in the project directory. Download argparse.py from here, copy it to the project directory, and make sure to set the file as executable by the right owner: https://code.google.com/p/argparse/source/browse/argparse.py  For more about this, check out the following answer about argparse: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21359591/2146138

Comment: @NathanBasanese thanks that was only solution as both pip and easy_install was missing from RHEL5 repo

Answer (score 0):

argparse is a Python standard library,that mean you can just use

```
import argparse
```

to use it

Comment: Which version? I got the error `ImportError: No module named argparse`

Comment: @yosei python >=2.7 or python >=3.2

Comment: The version of Python in RHEL6 and CentOS is 2.6. That is, it is NOT included as standard.