# Python 2.6 ImportError: No module named argparse

Tags: python, git, python-2.6, git-cola

I'm trying to run git-cola from Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 and receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "....../bin/git-cola", line 24, in <module>
from argparse import ArgumentParser
ImportError: No module named argparse
```

I think I have all of the required packages installed:

```
* git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.x86_64
* python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64
* PyQt4.x86_64 0:4.6.2-9.el6
* /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/argparse-1.2.1-py2.6.egg
```

I read in other blogs that there may be a problem with Python 2.6 and may need to move to 2.7.

Additional information - @iljau noticed that argparse is in a 32 bit lib, while the rest of python is in 64 bits. I would have expected that:

```
easy_install argparse
```

would have sorted this out and installed the 64 bit version.

Additional question: Does anyone know how to install the 64 bit version of argparse. It is not apparent to me from searching the internet. I will continue looking.

I installed argparse by downloading the tar file and

```
python setup.py install
```

However, it still installed it in the lib rather than lib64 path - and it looks like a 64 bit install. So something else must be the problem in referencing argparse properly. I don't know Python enough to debug it, but I suspect that git-cola needs some work for Python 2.6.

Comment: I've installed `argparse` on python2.6 lots of times.  It's a pure python module and there shouldn't be any real problems with it.  How did you install it?

Comment: As a sanity check, are you able to `import` any other modules from your `site-packges`?

Comment: `>>> import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)` see if you have the path site-packages there...

Comment: from the python interactive shell can you do `import argparse` do you got the same error.

Comment: Also `pip freeze | grep argparse` should output `argparse==1.2.1`.

Comment: @mgilson I used easy_install argparse

Comment: @recognosco result: >>> import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)
['',
 '/usr/lib64/python26.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info']

Comment: @yopy ... Yes, the same error

Comment: @iljau Doesn't work - I get the same error.

Comment: And from output of `import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)` it looks like your 32-bit and 64-bit `site-packages` are mixed for some reason.

Comment: It looks like `argparse` is installed for 32-bit python, while default python interpreter is 64-bit. I'd try installing `argparse` using 64-bit version of `pip` or `easy_install`. Or then explicitly invoke 32-bit `python`.

Comment: @iljau I agree that the 32bit/64bit is probably the problem. However, I assumed that easy_install would take care of sorting this out. How do I explicitly install the 64 bit argparse?

Comment: ["Howto install 32-bit libraries on 64-bit Linux using yum"](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/howto-install-32-bit-libraries-on-64-bit-linux-using-yum-505352/) may give some vague pointers.

Answer (score 5):

As a simple solution copy `argparse.py` from https://code.google.com/p/argparse/source/browse/argparse.py to your project folder.

---

And indeed, for Python 2.6 `argparse` needs to be installed separately.

From: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse

> As of Python >= 2.7 *..* the argparse module is maintained within the Python standard library. For users who still need to support Python < 2.7 *..* it is also provided as a separate package, which *..* also supports older Python versions.

But even after you install `argparse`, it may refuse to work for some mysterious reasons.

Additional debugging tips may be found in answers and comments to question ["ImportError: No module named argparse"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15093444/2419207).

Comment: According to the question, he's already installed the backport. Notice "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/argparse-1.2.1-py2.6.egg" in his list of required packages.

Comment: // , This worked for me, too. Make sure that argparse.py has the right owner, and that it is set as executable. Check @user3236698's answer for more about this.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on RHEL6 and the solution was installing the package **python-argparse.noarch**:

```
yum install python-argparse.noarch
```

then everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

The new packages were installed in the path:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

Installing them with sudo left the newly installed directories and files unreadable by all. A recursive chmod to open all the installed paths as readable to all solved the problem:

```
chmod -R u+rwX,go+rX,go-w <new directories and files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like argparse is missing.

```
yum install python-argparse
```